# global variable in javascript jquery interval

Tags: javascript, jquery, intervals

I have got code like this

```
var challegneListener;

$(document).ready(function(){
    var challegneListener = setInterval("challengeListenerBot()",5000);
});

function challengeListenerBot(){
    clearInterval(challegneListener);
}
```

And the problem is that the interval does not stop, becouse function called challengeListenerBot does not see challegneListener variable as number of interval. I must use jQuery to start interval when the document is ready.

Comment: Because var challegneListener is a local variable.

Comment: By the way, if you want the function to fire just once, use setTimeout instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var challegneListener = setInterval("challengeListenerBot()",5000);
});
```

To this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    challegneListener = setInterval("challengeListenerBot()",5000);
});
```

The problem is you're declaring inside your anonymous function, called when the DOM is ready, a new `challengneListener` variable. It hides the global variable, and only saves the setInterval ID to the local variable, which is garbage collected when its enclosing function has finished executing.

Comment: @KamilSolarczyk. That code still uses the evil `eval` you can fix it by removing the string, just give the function reference.

Comment: It's all good. good, even great developers make these mistakes all the time.

Comment: @KamilSolarczyk yeah, gdoron has a good point, you can just pass the name of the function, unquoted, and uncalled (without the parentheses), and it will work the same, and use JS best practices.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var challegneListener = setInterval("challengeListenerBot()",5000); 
});
```

Using var inside this function creates a new variable that is scoped to this function, meaning that the challegneListener variable that is defined globally remains undefined hence the interval not being cleared. Remove the var to fix this code.

Answer (score 0):

You hide the global variable, remove the `var`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    challegneListener = setInterval("challengeListenerBot()",5000); 
    // removed the var keyword, because it hides the global var.
});
```

Another thing, your code uses `eval`, change it to this:

```
challegneListener = setInterval(challengeListenerBot, 5000);
```